# 4 image panel grid with empty space in the middle (for email template)

Tags: html, css, image, sendgrid

I'm trying to recreate this 4 image structure in the way of the image below, however, I am doing this for an email template so the margin minus doesn't work.

generally, I tried to float left the images and replaced the margin minus with:

```
position: relative; top: -px;
```

, but that also doesn't work. am I even approaching this in the right way? or is there an easier way of doing this whole thing.

(the email template is done in SendGrid)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try with css grid and grid areas:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.item {
  padding: 1em;
}
.div1 { 
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3; 
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.div2 { 
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 2; 
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
.div3 { 
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 3 / 4; 
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.div4 { 
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 4; 
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">text</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1 item"> 1</div>
  <div class="div2 item"> 2</div>
  <div class="div3 item"> 3</div>
  <div class="div4 item"> 4</div>
</div>
```